# javascript: how to make multiple async calls in a loop

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, gulp

I have the following task in my gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
const spsync = require('gulp-spsync-creds').sync;
const sppkgDeploy = require('node-sppkg-deploy');

const config = require('./dev-config.json');
var coreOptions = {
        siteUrl: config.coreOptions.siteUrl,
        appCatalog: config.coreOptions.appCatalog
    };
var creds = {
        username: config.creds.username,
        password: config.creds.password
    };

build.task('upload-single-app', {
  execute: (config) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const pluginList = require('./config/plugin-deployment.json');
          if (pluginList)
          {
            for (let i = 0; i < pluginList.plugins.length; i++) {
                  const folderLocation = `./plugins/` + pluginList.plugins[i].name;
                  for (let x = 0; x < pluginList.plugins[i].sites.length; x++) {

                        console.log(pluginList.plugins[i].sites[x]);
                        return gulp.src(folderLocation)
                        .pipe(spsync({
                            "username": creds.username,
                            "password": creds.password,
                            "site": coreOptions.siteUrl + pluginList.plugins[i].sites[x],
                            "libraryPath": coreOptions.appCatalog,
                            "publish": true
                        }))
                        .on('finish', resolve);
                      }//end inner for
              }// end for
          } else {
            console.log("Plugin list is empty");
          }
        });
  }
});
```

And this is the JSON data that drives this:

```
{
  "plugins":
  [
    {
      "name": "Bluebeam.OpenRevuExtension.sppkg",
      "description":"some description",
      "version":"20.2.30.5",
      "sites":["sp_site1","sp_site2"]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run this code, it successfully deploys the package to site1, but not site 2.  There are no errors.  This is what the output looks like:

```
devbox:plugintest admin$ gulp upload-single-app
Build target: DEBUG
[14:51:48] Using gulpfile /src/plugintest/gulpfile.js
[14:51:48] Starting gulp
[14:51:48] Starting 'upload-single-app'...
sp_site1
[14:51:48] Uploading Bluebeam.OpenRevuExtension.sppkg
[14:51:50] Upload successful 1919ms
[14:51:51] Published file 982ms
[14:51:51] Finished 'upload-single-app' after 2.92 s
[14:51:51] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[14:51:52] Project plugintest version:1.0.0
[14:51:52] Build tools version:3.12.1
[14:51:52] Node version:v10.24.1
[14:51:52] Total duration:6.48 s
```

I'm not very familiar with async coding in JS but I'm thinking maybe I refactor so i have 2 separate tasks.
One will have the logic to loop through the JSON data... and for each it will call a separate build task.  Something like this: (pseudocode)

```
build.task('main', {
     for each plugin in json file {
         for each site I need to deploy to {
             call build.task('upload_app');
             call build.task('deploy_app');
         }
     }
  });
```

**Questions**

Is this a good approach? Can you give me some pointers on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It kind of depends what you need. Do you need to wait for each site to deploy before moving on to the next and go by them one by one (in sequence)? Or do you want to deploy them all at once and finish the gulp task whenever they are all done (in parallel)?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier i  think parallel is ok, as long as there's a way for me to capture results from each attempt

Answer (score 0):

Your current behavior happens because you have a single `Promise` which resolves on the first iteration of the loop by calling `resolve` when the first site finishes.

### In Sequence

Instead you should have a `Promise` per site in the second loop. Combined with an `async / await` syntax, wait for each `Promise` in the loop to resolve before moving on the next one.

```
build.task("upload-single-app", {
  execute: async () => {
    const pluginList = require("./config/plugin-deployment.json");

    if (!pluginList) {
      return;
    }
    
    for (const { name, sites } of pluginList.plugins) {
      const folderLocation = `./plugins/${name}`;

      for (const site of sites) {
        // Here await each gulp pipeline to finish before moving on to the next.
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
          gulp
            .src(folderLocation)
            .pipe(
              spsync({
                username: creds.username,
                password: creds.password,
                site: coreOptions.siteUrl + site,
                libraryPath: coreOptions.appCatalog,
                publish: true,
              })
            )
            .on("finish", resolve);
        });
      }
    }
  },
});
```

### In Parallel

You could also loop over each site and return a `Promise` with the `map` method of an array. Then collect all promises in a single array and use `Promise.all()` to wait until all promises have fulfilled.

```
build.task("upload-single-app", {
  execute: async () => {
    const pluginList = require("./config/plugin-deployment.json");

    if (!pluginList) {
      return;
    }
    
    const pluginBuilds = await Promise.all(pluginList.plugins.flatMap(({ name, sites }) => {
      const folderLocation = `./plugins/${name}`;

      return sites.map(site => new Promise((resolve) => {
        gulp
          .src(folderLocation)
          .pipe(
            spsync({
              username: creds.username,
              password: creds.password,
              site: coreOptions.siteUrl + site,
              libraryPath: coreOptions.appCatalog,
              publish: true,
            })
          )
          .on("finish", resolve);
      }));
    }));

    return pluginBuilds;
  },
});
```

Comment: 'pluginList.plugins.flatMap is not a function' is what I'm getting when I try the parallel example.